# Easy way to change the background color of a line

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I understand that vim can set syntax for highlighting by defining the classes.

However, this is a bit tedious.

Is there an easy way to change the background of a line, e.g. is there a way by writing

```
This is the line. ///LightBlue///
```

, the background color would be light blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
highlight LightBlue guibg=#00afff ctermbg=039
match LightBlue /^.*lightblue.*$/
```

Where the pattern: `^.*lightblue.*$` is identifying the lines that you would like to highlight in light blue (in this example all the lines that contains `lightblue`).

Comment: thanks a lot! works like a charm

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: is there a limitation that we can't have two highlights, e.g. one lin of lightblue and another with lightgreen?

Comment: The `:match` call override each other but with the `syntax` call you can have concurrent highlighting (that shouldn't overlap each other though).

Answer (score 1):

Using `:highlight` commands, only changes those parts of a line, that have content. The empty lines won't be colored.

A few years ago, I created a plugin [BackgroundColor](https://github.com/chrisbra/BackgroundColor.vim), that allows to highlight the complete line using Signs.

With that, you can have real background colors like this:
[image]

Just use the ex commands `:Green`, `:Blue` etc.